# Is there a first-order sentence in the language of rings that can distinguish modular integers from products of modular integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, ring-theory

Let's restrict attention to rings that are products of rings of the form $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. **Is there a first-order sentence in the language of rings that can distinguish rings that can be additively generated from a single element like $\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$ from those that cannot like $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$?**

For any given $n$, there is a first-order sentence expressing the existence of an element with additive order $n$, i.e. $\exists a \mathop. a \neq 0 \land a + a \neq 0 \land a + a + a = 0$ when $n=3$. However, I don't know of any sentences off the top of my head that work for all of the above rings independent of $n$.

The first-order sentence can have arbitrary behavior on rings outside of the above class such as $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ etc.

---

**What follows is motivation and why I'm interested in this.**

I'm trying to learn more about modules and I'm investigating $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ and trying to classify its finite modules.

I know that the order of each element must divide 10 from [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484368/a-group-is-a-mathbb-z-n-module-if-and-only-if-the-order-of-every-element-in-t), which limits my ability to produce "weird" modules.

I also know that [every finite Abelian group is isomorphic to direct product of cyclic groups, each with prime power order](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups).

These two things, taken together, limit my ability to make "weird" modules with $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ as my ring, since as a group my module must factor into cyclic groups and I can't get any orders that don't divide $10$. The next thing I'm going to do is try out $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ or something as my ring and puzzle through how to make it a ring action in some way.

The ring $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ seems quite different from $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ intuitively, so I'm wondering if there's a first-order way to distinguish them.

EDIT: (the question originally said $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, which is not distinct from $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: Well, for $m,n$ relatively prime, $\mathbb Z/mn\approx \mathbb Z/m\oplus \mathbb Z/n$, so they'd not be distinguishable at all!

Comment: @paulgarrett Note that the OP was careful to say "those that cannot" - so this rules such rings out.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, well, yes, but the last sentence in the question made me wonder...

Comment: Noah is giving me more credit than I deserve. I wasn't actively thinking about what happens when $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @paulgarrett Oh huh, I missed that. :P ooops

Comment: Responding to your motivation: A $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$-module is just an abelian group $G$ such that for all $g\in G$, $10g = 0$. Equivalently, every element of $G$ has order dividing $10$. By the classification of finite abelian groups, this implies that a finite $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$-module has the form $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n\times (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^m$ where  $n$ and $m$ are finite. An alternative classification is $(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z})^n\times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^m$ or $(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z})^n\times (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^m$ where $n$ and $m$ are finite.

Comment: An easy characterization of modules over products of rings is given here by egreg: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1707529/7062 I'm not writing the characterization in the comment in case you want to figure it out for yourself! But it makes it very easy to classify modules over $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (and modules over any other finite product of "modular arithemetic" rings).